# OCI runtime create failed

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am trying to dockerize a spring boot service. I started referring to this [article](https://www.javainuse.com/devOps/docker/docker-war). I was able to build the image but could not run it. When i try to run the container it fails with below error.

> OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:345: starting container
>   process caused \"exec: \\"catalina.sh\\": executable file not found
>   in $PATH\": unknown

**Command used to build image :** docker build --tag=my-image . --no-cache 
**Command used to run container  :** docker container run -p 8080:8080 my-image

Docker File:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
COPY ./target/my-service.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/my-service.war
CMD ["catalina.sh","run"]
```

I am using Windows 10 Docker Desktop and I tried using other base images, reset docker but none of it solve the problem. Please help me with some suggestions.

Regards,
Jai

Comment: It seems `catalina.sh` file location is not present in `$PATH` environment variable. Try this `docker run -it --rm my-image /bin/sh` You will enter in the container shell. Now check for the location of `catalina.sh` also verify the contents of `$PATH` using `echo $PATH` I bet catalina.sh location will not be present there. Once you get the exact location of `catalina.sh` put that entire file location in your dockerfile `CMD ["/path/to/catalina.sh","run"]` and build and run the container. It should work now. Let me know.

Comment: @mchawre i could see that in /usr/local/tomcat only webapps folder is available and nothing else! Ideally bin logs and other folders should be there

Comment: Have you found catalina.sh file somewhere in the container?

Answer (score 2):

`catalina.sh` is from `tomcat`.

From the [article](https://www.javainuse.com/devOps/docker/docker-war) you mentioned in the post, it told you to use:

```
From tomcat:8.0.51-jre8-alpine
CMD ["catalina.sh","run"]
```

But, you now use:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
CMD ["catalina.sh","run"]
```

The base image you used do not have tomcat installed, so you certainly could not find `catalina.sh`.

Comment: I have the same error with 'tomcat:8.5.47-jdk8-openjdk'

Answer (score 1):

use following command to find catalina.sh

1.docker run -it --rm (ur_image_name) /bin/bash
2./usr/local/tomcat/bin
3.ls

It will list out all file in bin directory.There you will see catalina.sh.
Now Copy the whole path of catalina.sh like in my case it is "\usr\local\tomcat\bin\catlina.sh"

and paste this in DockerFile in CMD like this
CMD ["\usr\local\tomcat\bin\catlina.sh","run"]